# javascript close a popup on submit

Tags: javascript, popup, form-submit

Ok.  I've seen this question as been unanswered for over 10 years..

How do you submit and close a popup in one button call.

suggestions run thus.

```
function saveNClose()
{
  document.form.submit();
  self.close();
}
this doesn't work because the submit has a redirect, and the self.close is never reached.
```

---

```
function closeLaterNSaveNow();
{
  setTimeout("window.close()",5000);
  document.form.submit();
}
same problem..  the close is never called because the script for the page is gone.
```

---

```
function closeNowNSubmit()
{
  self.close(); 
 document.form.submit();
}
the window closes, but nothing gets saved.  server doesn't even get notified of anything..
```

---

```
<input class='btn btn-success' disabled='disabled' id='SubmitFinal' onclick='closeWindow()' type='submit' value='Finish'>
Well then there's no validation of the data.  it submits before the function is called.
```

Anyone solve this?  I found the same solutions dating back to 2002, and some as recent as this month.  I shall continue to look, but I'm hoping someone has nailed it and that that someone answers here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical solution is to output a JS snippet that will close the window as a resulting page after submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.close();
</script>
```

Another solution would be to submit form's data via AJAX, and close the window when request has finished. You can use [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for that:

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm(function() { 
    window.close();
})
```

Comment: any idea how to change the resulting page?  is that done outside of the script?

Comment: @daveatflow The resulting page is what your backend generate. I assumed that you have control over the server-side app as well.

Comment: I do in fact have control of this.  I had hoped to accomplish this in javascript alone.... seems I'm fated to mix tech.  Yeck, but thanks.